How can I access method annotations in my custom annotation injected parameter?
I am using Jersey 2.42. I have an annotation which I apply to my resource methods.
@Path("/stuff")
public class MyResources {
  @GET
  @MyAnnotation("someValue")
  public Response getTheThing(@MyInjectedParam MyType value) {
    // ...
  }
}

MyAnnotation is a regular method-level annotation. Nothing special about it.
MyInjectedParam is configured via a Feature, like so:
public class MyInjectedParamFeature implements Feature {
  @Override
  public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
    context.register(new AbstractBinder() {
      @Override
      protected void configure() {
        bindFactory(MyInjectedParamFactory.class)
                .to(MyType.class)
                .proxy(true)
                .proxyForSameScope(false)
                .in(RequestScoped.class)
        ;

        bind(MyInjectedParamInjectResolver.class)
                .to(new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<MyInjectedParam>>(){})
                .in(Singleton.class);
      }
    });

    return true;
  }
}

And the factory is as you would expect:
public class MyInjectedParamFactory implements Factory<MyType> {
  @Inject ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

  @Override MyType provide() {
   // ...MyType construction would like to check for MyAnnotation on the method
   // and use its value, but resourceInfo.getResourceMethod() is null!
  }
}

but as the comment says, when my provide() method is called, the ResourceInfo.getResourceMethod() call returns null.
Is there any way I can get these two annotations to work together, so that the injection code for the resource method parameter has access to method-level annotations?
I have tried having MyAnnotation be a the trigger for a name-bound filter, but it suffers from the same problem. When parameter injection happens, I can't access anything that the filter has access to in order to pass information to the injection code.

There was a recent bug fix regarding HK2 factories in 2.43. That bug could affect the functionality in 2.42

Using this answer and the use of the debugger I was able to implement this in a different way that allowed me to access the matched java.lang.reflect.Method and hence its annotations during provision of the value.
I changed the injection to use the ValueParamProvider exactly as described in the linked answer. Inside its getValueProvider method, where I create the lamba to return, I can access the method like so:
import java.util.function.Function;

import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Parameter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ValueParamProvider;

public class MyInjectedValueParamProvider implements ValueParamProvider {
  @Override
  public Function<ContainerRequest, ?> getValueProvider(Parameter parameter) {
    if (parameter.getRawType().equals(MyType.class)) {
      return (ContainerRequest req) -> {
        Method resourceMethod = req.getUriInfo().getMatchedResourceMethod().getInvocable().getDefinitionMethod();
        // ...now I can look for whatever annotations I need to query to provide
        // the correct value
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
}

